# Load CSV with non-standard formatting using SSIS

Tags: c#, sql-server, csv, ssis, etl

I'm tasked with loading accounting transactions that come over in a csv file. The file contains one row of header information applied to the entire file but for some reason it groups the data by account number above the transaction data but in the same column as the ID.

```
"ID","Name","Date","Debit","Credit","Balance"
,,,,,
"1150 - Cash in Bank",,,,,
"Starting Balance",,,,,"59,612.78"
615892,"Account Name 1","5/5/2018","2,100.00",,"61,712.78"
645761,"Account Name 2","5/7/2018",,7,"61,705.78"
615892,"Account Name 3","5/8/2018",,"2,144.33","59,561.45"
713300,"Account Name 4","5/8/2018","2,144.33",,"61,705.78"
713300,"Account Name 5","5/8/2018",,"2,144.33","59,561.45"
693615,"Account Name 6","5/9/2018",,"1,650.00","57,911.45"
"Net Change",,,,,"-1,701.33"
,,,"4,244.33","5,945.66","57,911.45"
"3150 - Owner Contribution",,,,,
"Starting Balance",,,,,0
713300,"Account Name 4","5/8/2018",,"2,144.33","-2,144.33"
"Net Change",,,,,"-2,144.33"
,,,0,"2,144.33","-2,144.33"
```

Can someone get me started on how I can process this? I see how to logically accomplish this with just a few variables and row by row processing but im not a C# or front end developer at all. My biggest problem seems to be that you cant write a piece and test it like SQL. I can query the table, see the data and keep building it but with C# I need an entire script to work together. How do I start with a small block and expand? like even reading in the first account name to a variable and displaying it as a variable in a data flow task. Just something where I can send the code and get something back, seems like every script I find online has some compiling errors and I don't know enough to troubleshoot them yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution Overview

*I provided my answer in VB.Net because it may be easier to understand, especially you are not a C# developer*

- In the `Dataflow task` add a `Script Component` after the `Flat File Source`
- In mark all columns as Input Column and Add 8 Output Columns
- In the `Input0_ProcessInputRow` Check if ID column is not empty and it contains an integer to create an output row, Else if it contains the Account Number or Starting Balance store these values into variables, Else ignore the row.

## Detailed Solution

1. Add a Flat file connection manager, Select the text file
2. Change the Text Qualifier to `"`

[image]

3. Add a DataFlow Task
4. Inside the Data Flow Task add a Flat File Source, Script Component and OLEDB Destination

[image]

5. In the Script Component Select all Columns as Input Column
6. Add 8 Output Columns (Main columns + Account + Starting Balance) *(all of type `DT_STR`)*

[image]

7. Change the `OutputBuffer` `SynchronousInput` property to `None`

[image]

8. Select the Script Language to `Visual Basic`

[image]

9. In the Script Editor write the following Script

   ```
   Private AccountName as String = ""
   Private StartingBalance as String = ""
   ```

```vb
    Public Overrides Sub Input0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As Input0Buffer)

        If Not Row.ID_IsNull AndAlso
                Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Row.ID.Trim) Then


            'Skip Bad Rows
            If Row.ID = "" Then Exit Sub

            If Integer.TryParse(Row.ID,New Integer) Then

                Output0Buffer.AddRow()
                Output0Buffer.ID = Row.ID
                Output0Buffer.Name = Row.Name
                Output0Buffer.Date = Row.Date
                Output0Buffer.Debit = Row.Debit
                Output0Buffer.Credit = Row.Credit
                Output0Buffer.Balance = Row.Balance
                Output0Buffer.Account = AccountName
                Output0Buffer.StartingBalance = StartingBalance

            Elseif Row.ID.Contains("Starting Balance") Then

                StartingBalance = Row.Balance

            Elseif Row.ID.Contains("-") Then

                AccountName = Row.ID

            Else 


                'Ignore Row 
                Exit Sub

            End If






        End If

    End Sub
```

10. Map the Output Columns to the Destination Columns
11. The output will be:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This should get all of that into a DataTable structure that you can then use to assign out or do whatever with. If you need a different kind of end object let me know.

```
        var data = string.Empty; //String var to hold file
        var tbl = new DataTable("MyData"); //Tmp dataTable object
        using (var fs = new StreamReader(@"C:\Temp\test.csv")) //Open file
            data = fs.ReadToEnd(); //Read entirely into data variable

        var rows = data.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); //Split into array by lines. RemoveEmpty's for end of file extra lines.

        var cnt = 0; //Counter to know header
        foreach (var row in rows) //Iterate rows
        {
            var cells = row.Split(new string[] { "\",\"" }, StringSplitOptions.None); //Split row into cells. Leave empties here cause some cells might be empty.
            if (cnt == 0) foreach (var cell in cells) //If is header row add columns
                    tbl.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(cell));
            else //Else data row
            {
                var dataRow = tbl.NewRow(); //New row
                dataRow.ItemArray = cells; //Assign cell values
                tbl.Rows.Add(dataRow); //Add row to table.
            }
            cnt++;
        }
```

EDIT: Cleaned up using and added comments.

EDIT2: Here's a streaming version if the files are to large:

```
        var cnt = 0; //Row counter
        var tbl = new DataTable("MyData"); //Tmp dataTable object
        using (var fs = new StreamReader(@"C:\Temp\test.csv")) //Load file
        {
            do //Start loop
            {
                var row = fs.ReadLine(); //Get first line
                var cells = row.Split(new string[] { "\",\"" }, StringSplitOptions.None); //Split into cells
                if (cnt == 0) //If is header row
                {
                    foreach (var cell in cells) //For each header
                        tbl.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(cell)); //Add Column
                } else { //Not header row
                    var dataRow = tbl.NewRow(); //Create new row based on tmp table
                    dataRow.ItemArray = cells; //Assign cell values
                    tbl.Rows.Add(row); //Add row to table
                }
                cnt++;
            } while (!fs.EndOfStream); //If not done loop
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this post.  Having gone through a very similar experience just 1 day ago, I would recommend running the Macro below (it can be run in Excel or CSV, but you can't save the code if you save your changes with a CSV extension).

```
' Add reference to Microsoft Active X Data Objects 2.8 Library                                                           

Sub testexportsql()
    Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim ServerName As String
    Dim DatabaseName As String
    Dim TableName As String
    Dim UserID As String
    Dim Password As String
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim RowCounter As Long

    Dim NoOfFields As Integer
    Dim StartRow As Long
    Dim EndRow As Long

    Dim ColCounter As Integer


    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset


    ServerName = "server_name" ' Enter your server name here
    DatabaseName = "db_name" ' Enter your  database name here
    TableName = "table_name" ' Enter your Table name here
    UserID = "" ' Enter your user ID here
     ' (Leave ID and Password blank if using windows Authentification")
    Password = "" ' Enter your password here
    NoOfFields = 10 ' Enter number of fields to update (eg. columns in your worksheet)
    StartRow = 2 ' Enter row in sheet to start reading  records
    EndRow = 100 ' Enter row of last record in sheet

     '  CHANGES
    Dim shtSheetToWork As Worksheet
    Set shtSheetToWork = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet_name")
     '********

    Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection
    Cn.Open "Driver={SQL Server};Server=" & ServerName & ";Database=" & DatabaseName & _
    ";Uid=" & UserID & ";Pwd=" & Password & ";"

    rs.Open TableName, Cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic

     'EndRow = shtSheetToWork.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For RowCounter = StartRow To EndRow
        rs.AddNew
        For ColCounter = 1 To NoOfFields
            rs(ColCounter - 1) = shtSheetToWork.Cells(RowCounter, ColCounter)
        Next ColCounter
        Debug.Print RowCounter
    Next RowCounter
    rs.UpdateBatch

     ' Tidy up
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Cn.Close
    Set Cn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Hopefully this solution works for you.  It definitely worked for me.